# iTerm2 Vim alt+right/left arrow

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2

As a Linux user, I am very used to jump from word to word in vim/nano using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>right</kbd>.

This doesn't seem to work properly using iTerm, I am using zsh, I tried adding;

```
bindkey -e
bindkey '^[[1;9C' forward-word
bindkey '^[[1;9D' backward-word
```

It does work, but inside zsh only, then I commented those lines and added in iTerm a keyboard shortcut;

[image]

It does work, but only for the <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>left</kbd>

How can I make it work for the right arrow too?

Answer (score 14):

In iTerm's properties go to Profiles -> Keys and setup there

- For <kbd>⌥→</kbd> Send Escape Sequence `[1;5C`
- For <kbd>⌥←</kbd> Send Escape Sequence `[1;5D`

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work for me. The escape sequences are sent, but vim only moves one space back and forth. Running the default vim 7.3 that comes with OS X 10.8. Ideally, I'd like to change it on vim's side, not tweaking the defaults of the Terminal emulator (since that'll result in better portability).

Comment: That's weird, it works both in vim (from homebrew, not a default one) and zsh with the default configuration from oh-my-zsh (in ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/key-bindings.sh).

Comment: Doesn't work here either, I can use alt + arrow in inside zsh, in Vim it only works with shift + arrow :(

Comment: I checked it one more time on available remote systems (ubuntu 13.04, stable debian, and scientific linux) and it works everywhere.
What is the output when you press Control+V, ⌥→? For me it is ^[[1;5C

Comment: Works for me: iTerm/Vi + zsh

Answer (score 8):

Start by viewing the key code your terminal is sending to vim:

```
$ sed -n l
^[[1;9D
```

In the above example, i ran the sed command and pressed <kbd>Alt + Left</kbd>.

The `^[[1;9D` is the escaped sequence being sent to vim, so we can user that for our mapping.

Add to vimrc:

```
map <Esc>[1;9D :tabn<CR>
```

### alternative solution for macOS

if `sed -nl` is not working as expected, try CTRL + V instead

> You can determine the current mapping using the "control-V trick": First press control-V, then the keystroke you like to examine. This will print the characters that are sent to the terminal.
> http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Backspace_and_Delete_key_reversed

For example typing control-V + `delete` prints `^?`. I have only verified this on macOS 11.

Comment: what's the key code for `delete`?

Comment: try `ctrl + v` and then press the delete key instead of the sed cmd which prints nothing. i get this (running osx): `^?`

Answer (score 1):

I read another post describing that for option-left and option right, you need to bind them to the actions ^[b and ^[f, respectively. That is, you bind them to "Send escape sequence" and bind key b and f.

http://elweb.co/making-iterm-2-work-with-normal-mac-osx-keyboard-shortcuts/

Comment: +1! I found similar instructions here: https://coderwall.com/p/h6yfda/use-and-to-jump-forwards-backwards-words-in-iterm-2-on-os-x

Answer (score 0):

None of those answers worked for me.
I ended up loading a linux VM and checked what I'd get with `<Alt-ARROW>`.

The 4 escape sequences which worked for me are those:

- `<Alt+Up>`:  `[1;3A`
- `<Alt+Down>`:  `[1;3B`
- `<Alt+Right>`:  `[1;3C`
- `<Alt+Left>`:  `[1;3D`

Be careful to edit the Profile keys and not the main ones which will be overridden by the Profile ones (where Alt + Arrows are set by default to an Hex Sequence which didn't work with vim).

Answer (score -1):

Just an other possible solution, vim offers word motions on its own, see:

```
:help word-motions
```

Comment: You should include the essential information instead of just putting a reference here.